# How to generate MySQL databse tables script using mvc application with Entity Framework

Tags: mysql

As part of automation we want to create MySQL DB script from Existing DB. Actually we can't use EF Code Firts migration because tables are more than 1000. So timeout error will come. So the alternative is generate script from existing db using MVC application.

Comment: what have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you can export your tables data to `.csv` comma separated value files, you can do a easy migration with `LOAD DATA INFILE`. My experience is not from db to db. Just from excel to MySQL db. I exported excel sheets as a `somedata.csv` files. And then I created a table that I need to and I use this scripts to import to MySQL database. I think you can use it.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'somedata.csv' INTO TABLE some_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

So, first you need to create your tables' structure again.
Second, you need to export your data to csv files.
Third, you can do import specific data by using `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

It is not the entire great way. But It can be fast enough. A table with more than 1 millions record will imported with just a minute. You can see
`LOAD DATA INFILE` documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)